# How to run django server on visual studio 2019?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, debugging

I normally work with Pycharm or vs code to run my django project, but I heard the debugging on visual studio is better.

I openend the project on visual studio and set my environment and selected manage.py as startup file

I try to run it but I get this message on cmd:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/python/learn-django-in-visual-studio-step-01-project-and-solution?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

After opening your project in Visual Studio Code, click terminal at the top and new terminal. when you see ready terminal at the button type: python manage.py runserver.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use it on visual studio and not visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

1 - Set the manager.py as Startup Item

2 - Click on Debug and Launch Settings with Right Click on manage.py file

3 - Click in Default on "Select a Debbuger"

4 - In the file Open put on file this: "scriptArguments": "runserver 0.0.0.0:80"

**In Windows run as 0.0.0.0**

[image: Selection Option]

[image: Set Parameters]